# Sorting algorithm using median-of-three?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am using the following algorithm, which I found on the internet and modified a little to find the median of three:

```
private static List<int> quicksort(List<int> arr)
{
    List<int> loe = new List<int>(), gt = new List<int>();

    if (arr.Count < 2)
        return arr;

    int middle = arr.Count / 2;
    int left = arr.First();
    int right = arr.Last();
    int MoT = 0;

    if (middle < left && middle < right) 
        MoT = middle;
    if (left < middle && left < right) 
        MoT = left;
    if (right < left && right < middle) 
        MoT = right;

    int pivot_val = arr[MoT]; //assign median pivot
    arr.RemoveAt(MoT);

    foreach (int i in arr)
    {
        if (i <= pivot_val)
            loe.Add(i);
        else if (i > pivot_val)
            gt.Add(i);
    }

    List<int> resultSet = new List<int>();
    resultSet.AddRange(quicksort(loe));

    if (loe.Count == 0)
        loe.Add(pivot_val);
    else
        gt.Add(pivot_val);

    resultSet.AddRange(quicksort(gt));
    return resultSet;
}
```

It correctly sorts an array of size 10, however, it only sorts and displays 7 numbers, instead of 10 numbers. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: That’s a particularly unreadable implementation. It would help tremendously to separate the individual parts (in particular the finding of the median and the partition step) into their own functions. And using `RemoveAt` is a pretty bad idea here, performance wise. (So is using `AddRange` instead of doing the thing in-place.)

Comment: Note that code  `if (middle < left && middle < right)...` finds **minimum** of three values, not median (it doesn't violate algo correctness, only slows run time)

Comment: Mmm... coursera "Algorithms: Design and Analysis" ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the pivot value back into `loe` AFTER you have already copied `loe` to the result, in the case where `loe` was empty. This does nothing. You should replace

```
loe.Add(pivot_val);
```

with

```
resultSet.Add(pivot_val);
```

or similar.

Comment: yep, this did the trick. It correctly sorts and displays all the 10 numbers now. thanks